# javascript callback function, onreadystatechange, in a simple ajax example

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm doing this tutorial in ajax and I don't understand one of the lines where a function is called. (line 6 in the code)

```
// this is called from an onload event in the html body  tag
function process() {
    if (xmlHttp) {
        try {
            xmlHttp.open("GET", "hello.txt", true);
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse; ***** THIS LINE HERE
            xmlHttp.send(null);
        } catch(e) {
            alert(e.toString());
        }
    };
}

handleServerResponse = function() {
    theD = document.getElementById('theD');

    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 1) {
        theD.innerHTML += "Status 1: server connectino established <br />";
    } else if (xmlHttp.readyState == 2) {
        theD.innerHTML += "Status 2: request recieved <br />";
    } else if (xmlHttp.readyState == 3) {
        theD.innerHTML += "Status 3: server processing task <br />";
    } else if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            try {
                text = xmlHttp.responseText;
                theD.innerHTML += 'status 4: request completed, response delievered.';
                theD.innerHTML += '<br />' + text;
            } catch(e) {
            }
        } else {
            alert("request cannont be completed by server (status 4)");
        };
    };
}
```

why wouldn't I call it with parenthesis? like: `xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse();`

when I do this it only seems to call the function once as it only prints out status 2. without the brackets though, when the function is declared as variable it seems to be called each time the state changes. why is this?

Also, why does the xmlHttp.onreadystatechange property execute more than once? the body tag should only be loaded once, thereby calling the function only once. why is it looping?

I'm definitely missing something, either with the ajax related objects or javascript function calling.

apart from the answer below, here is a good explanation of the "true" and "null" parameters in the process function: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Comment: There's a difference in referencing a function to be called later, and actually executing the function and returning the result. Adding the parentheses will always do the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why wouldn't I call it with parenthesis? like:
>   xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse();

Because on this line you are NOT CALLING THE FUNCTION. You are simply subscribing to an event (a callback) that will be called later by the `xmlHttp`instance and when the AJAX request gets some response from the server.

When you call `xmlHttp.send(null);` the AJAX request is sent to the server for processing. This function returns immediately and the next line of code is executed. Later, when the server has finished executing the request it will return some status code to the client along with the response body. It is at that moment that the actual `handleServerResponse` function will get executed.

Comment: ok, so the XMLHttpRequest object will keep track of statechanges and  call the handleServerResponse function (the callback) whenever it detects a change of state by calling the onreadystatechange property?

Comment: The way `XMLHttpRequest` is implemented will depend on the actual browser and underlying operating system. This is native javascript object that provides you with the `onreadystatechange` property which represents a reference to a function that will be invoked when the AJAX call succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

handleServerResponse is actually the reference to the function itself. Adding the parenthesis would actually make a call to that function and store the result in xmlHttp.onreadystatechange. In this case, we want to let xmlHttp know what will it have to do once the readyState changes (we call that a callback).